# regex with multiple partial and exact patterns via alternation

Tags: python, regex

I have an extremely long list of criteria that I am using to regex match via pandas str.contains() and then create an indicator flag like so:

```
criteria_list = ['pattern1','pattern2','pattern3']

criteria_search_pattern = '|'.join(criteria_list)

df_transactions['flag'] = (df_transactions['text'].str.contains(criteria_search_pattern)).astype(int)
```

This approach works well for me.  However, I have noticed that there are some criteria that I need to handle more strictly to avoid collisions.  My question is whether it would be possible to somehow mix partial and exact patterns?

For example:

```
partial pattern|(no prior characters permitted)partial pattern|partial pattern(no trailing characters permitted)|exact pattern
```

**EDIT:**

Here are some concrete examples:

```
963, 
E27, 
27, 
95678, 
956, 
95312

96 partial match (no extra criteria), return true 
E27 partial match (no prior characters permitted), return false 
276 partial match (no prior characters permitted), return true
95678 partial match (no trailing characters permitted), return false
6956 partial match (no trailing characters permitted), return true
95312 exact match, return true
```

Comment: It's probably possible, most things are.  Can you provide some clear examples of things you do/do not want to match?

Comment: If you are only interested in a boolean result, then what you have seems sufficient.

Comment: Yes, but realise that with the pipe the order matters. /foo|foobar|foo\w+/g  will only match 'foo' in 'foobarz'.

Comment: Thanks all.  I updated to provide some concrete examples.

Comment: `"^95312$|96|27|956"` is the pattern that works for this current edited scenario.

Comment: I clarified my examples to make sure I am describing the behavior I am looking for more accurately.

Comment: Try [`^95312$|^27|96|956$`](https://regex101.com/r/HgBu9e/2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `partial pattern|pattern with prior characters ignored$|^pattern with trailing characters ignored|^exact pattern$`. `^x` means that `x` should be at the beginning of your string, `x$` means that `x` should be at the end.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I have also clarified my examples to make sure I described the behaviors accurately.